# Android MenuItemCompat.getActionView(MenuItem) return null

Tags: android

I am trying to integrate v7 appcompat library to implement ActionBar. I am able to inflate the
  action bar with menu items but the problem is I am unable to get the reference to the menu  item
  using MenuItemCompat.getActionView() call. It returns null.

Here is my code.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    MenuItem copyItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_copy);        
    TextView copyView = (TextView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(copyItem);



    return true;
}
```

main.xml
  .........................

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="Search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_copy"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_content_copy"
    android:title="Copy"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_social_share"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

styles.xml

.................

```
 <resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

```
 manifest.xml

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.hmkcode.android.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Please tell where I am missing something.

Thanks

Comment: Do you use ActionBarActivity?

Comment: Yes I am using ActionBarActivity.

Comment: do not you need this `app:actionViewClass`?

Comment: Do I need to to add app:actionViewClass for each action item in action bar?

Answer (score 1):

> Please tell where I am missing something.

You have no action views defined in your menu XML resource. Hence, `getActionView()` is supposed to return `null`.

If you want `getActionView()` to return a non-`null` value, you need to follow [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionView) and add an action view to your menu XML resource, such as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:title="@string/action_search"
          android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
          yourapp:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: I am not putting search item in action bar. How do I get the reference of non-SearchView related item.  I want to just keep to action item like cart menu item and option menu item.

Comment: @user3358863: If you are using `actionViewClass` or `actionLayout`, you will use `getActionView()` to get at the instance of that widget (or, for `actionLayout`, the root of whatever view hierarchy was defined by the layout file). If you are not using those attributes, you do not have access to anything, as those are not your widgets.

Comment: Here is the updated xml.                                                sd    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_copy"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_content_copy"
    android:title="Copy"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_social_share"
    android:title="Share"/>

Comment: @user3358863: You have no access to any widgets in that action bar. They are not your widgets, as you did not define or create them. They are the action bar's widgets.

Comment: OK. So My requirement is to show two action items in action bar, one is cart menu item and another is option menu. How I will implement it, inflate it so that I can access to that action item and set text on it.

Comment: Any helpfull link which has full implementation of appcompat ActionBar with actions on each menu item.

Comment: @user3358863: I have no idea what you mean by "option menu". I have no idea why you think that "set text on it" is necessary or appropriate. I have no idea what "actions on each menu item" means. Asking for "any helpfull link" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Please ask a new Stack Overflow question where you explain **completely and precisely** what you mean by these things (and not ask for off-site resources). With luck, somebody will be able to help you.

Comment: See the Problem is in my app I am using ActionBarSherlock to give support of actionbar to lower level devices. Now I want to migrate to v7 appcompat. While migrating I am facing these issues. Set text on action item means setting values on action item like text color, font size etc.